# Password Authentication For AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passwords, filezilla

good day. I have an EC2 instance of AWS where I host my website. I currently upload files using Filezilla. To connect I use the .pem file. My question is if this is the safest thing or should I create a password for the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keypairs are much safer for accessing a system. Keypairs are effectively impossible to be guessed and they are not transmitted during login.

See similar discussions:

- [Why is using an SSH key more secure than using passwords? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/why-is-using-an-ssh-key-more-secure-than-using-passwords)
- [cryptography - Is using a public-key for logging in to SSH any better than saving a password? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/is-using-a-public-key-for-logging-in-to-ssh-any-better-than-saving-a-password)